# bad char after creating a Database from csv

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to create a database using mongoid but it fails to find the create method. I am trying to create 2 databases based on csv files:

extract_data class:

```
class ExtractData

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  def self.create_all_databases
    @cbsa2msa = DbForCsv.import!('./share/private/csv/cbsa_to_msa.csv')
    @zip2cbsa = DbForCsv.import!('./share/private/csv/zip_to_cbsa.csv')
  end

  def self.show_all_database
    ap @cbsa2msa.all.to_a
    ap @zip2cbsa.all.to_a
  end

end
```

the class DbForCSV works as below:

```
class DbForCsv
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  def self.import!(file_path)
    columns = []
    instances = []
    CSV.foreach(file_path, encoding: 'iso-8859-1:UTF-8') do |row|
      if columns.empty?
        # We dont want attributes with whitespaces
        columns = row.collect { |c| c.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') }
        next
      end
      instances << create!(build_attributes(row, columns))
    end
    instances
  end

  private

  def self.build_attributes(row, columns)
    attrs = {}
    columns.each_with_index do |column, index|
      attrs[column] = row[index]
    end
    ap attrs
    attrs
  end
end
```

I am not aware of all fields and it may change in time. that's why I have create database and generic mehtods.

I have also another issue after having fixed the 'create!' issue.

I am using the encoding to make sure only UTF8 char are handled but I still see:

```
{
       "ï»¿zip" => "71964",
         "cbsa" => "31680",
    "res_ratio" => "0.086511098",
    "bus_ratio" => "0.012048193",
    "oth_ratio" => "0.000000000",
    "tot_ratio" => "0.082435345"
}
```

when doing 'ap attrs' in the code. how to make sure that 'ï»¿zip' -> 'zip'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create!` is a class method but you're trying to call it as an instance method. Your `import!` method shouldn't be an instance method either, it should be a class method since it produces instances of your class:

```
def self.import!(file_path)
  #-^^^^
  # everything else would be the same...
end
```

You'd also make `build_attributes` a class method since it is just a helper method for another class method:

```
def self.build_attributes
  #...
end
```

And then you don't need that odd looking `new` call when using `import!`:

```
def self.create_all_databases
  @cbsa2msa = DbForCsv.import!('./share/private/csv/cbsa_to_msa.csv')
  @zip2cbsa = DbForCsv.import!('./share/private/csv/zip_to_cbsa.csv')
end
```